# Как выполнить js файл в npm script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, frontend, npm

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, как через npm скрипты запустить js из файла?**

Я пытался по простому:

1. Cоздал файл **test.js** со своим js котодом который нужно выполнить по команде
2. добавил в файл package.json, в раздел scripts, строкчку: **"com": "./test.js"** - путь к файлу.
3. В консоли выполняю команду **npm run com**

Но получаю ошибку **"var: not found"** - т.е. как я полнимаю npm скрипты не понимают js синтаксиса, верно? Если так, то на каком языки для них нужно писать скрипты? И как легче всего заставить его выполнить js скрипт?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здесь слово `scripts` ни как не связано с `js`, воспринимайте это скорее, как `bash-скрипты`. То есть `npm run script-name` просто вызовет вашу команду, которую вы указали, в консоль. В вашем случае, вы хотите запустить `js` файл без интерпретатора.

Что бы все завелось, вам нужен `node.js`, которые уже может запускать скрипты в своем окружении. Скачать тут https://nodejs.org

После того, как установили, поменяйте ваш `package.json`:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "com": "node ./test.js",
  }
}

// в командной строке
npm run com
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Comment: Ещё можно в скрипте первой строкой правильный шебанг написать `#!/usr/bin/env node` и выставить права на выполнение

Comment: Ну и раз у автора запускается npm, значит нода уже есть